# Questions about $\omega_1$ as a space (The Set of All Countable Ordinals)

Tags: general-topology, compactness, cardinals, ordinals

**The Set of All Countable Ordinals, $\omega_1$**

I'm trying to understand several things regarding $\omega_1$ and trying to get a better intuition. I have four questions regarding this space (in bold), but I also tried to summarize here what I know about the space, hoping that it helps anyone who comes across this post in the future. Thank you for any insights.

**1) Definition**

- $\omega_1$ denotes the set of all countable ordinals and $\{\omega_1\}$ is the first uncountable ordinal.
- Elements are all countable ordinals - I imagine the $\omega_1$ space as $0, 1, 2, 3, .... \omega, \omega + 1, \omega + 2, ... \omega + \omega, ... \omega * \omega, ...\omega_1 $
- The element $\{ \omega_1 \}$ itself is not part of the space. It is the limit point.
- Topology is precisely the order topology, given by linear order $\leq$.

**2) Properties**

- $\omega_1$ is Hausdorff, locally compact
- Its cardinality is $\aleph_1$
- It is first-countable
- 0 and every successor ordinal $\alpha+1$ are isolated points
- It is not compact (since the collection $\{ [0,\alpha):\alpha<\omega_1 \}$ is an open cover with no finite subcover.
- Not connected. (For instance, 0 (the least element) is an isolated point, which means that the set {0} is open. It is also closed (as is any finite set in ω1 or any other Hausdorff space) and so its complement is open. Thus we have written $\omega_1$ as a union of two nonempty disjoint open sets, so it is not connected.)
- Not separable
- **Is it a discrete space?**
- **How do the open and closed subspaces look?**
- **Is it (strongly) zero-dimensional? How does the basis look?**
- **Are clopen subspaces homeomorphic to the whole space?**

Comment: It is not discrete. For example $\omega$ is a limit point. (More generally any limit ordinal.)

Comment: Separately, any isolated point yields a nonempty clopen subspace - so the answer to your last question is most definitely negative.

Comment: A slightly more interesting but straightforward question about clopen subspaces is whether for ever clopen subspace $C\subseteq\omega_1$, either $C$ or $\omega_1\setminus C$ is homeomorphic to $\omega_1$. Can you prove or find a counterexample?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I dont understand your note "any isolated point yields a nonempty clopen subspace" - could you please explain more? Thank you!

Comment: @TerezaTizkova If $a$ is an isolated point in a ($T_1$) space $\mathcal{X}$, then $\{a\}$ is a nonempty clopen subspace of $\mathcal{X}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minor correction: $\omega_1$ is *both* the first uncountable ordinal *and* the set of countable ordinals. $\{\omega_1\}$ is just a singleton set that contains it as its single element, so far from uncountable nor an ordinal.

I agree fully with all the properties.

Limit ordinals (so the non-succesor ones) like $\omega, \omega+\omega, \omega\cdot \omega, \omega^\omega$ (all in ordinal arithmetic) which are all elements of $\omega_1$ are **not** isolated points: e.g. the first limit $\omega$ has as its basic neighbourhoods $(n, \omega+1)=(n,\omega]$ (open interval, $n < \omega$ so $n$ a natural. Just open intervals containing $\omega$ (we can assume that the right hand boundary point is $\omega+1$ WLOG and the left hand boundary point of the interval must lie below $\omega$). All these are infinite. These intervals are also clopen, as is easy to see.

So $\omega_1$ is not discrete, there are $\aleph_1$ many limits in it, all of which are not isolated.

So basic elements are $\{\alpha\}$ for $\alpha =0$ or $\alpha$ a successor and are clopen. A basic element for a limit is of the form $(\beta, \alpha]$ where $\beta < \alpha$. All of these are clopen (complement is $[0,\beta+1) \cup (\alpha, \rightarrow)$ which is open too).

I wouldn't know an easy form of a general clopen set.

- $\omega_1$ is (like all ordered spaces) hereditarily normal, aka $T_5$) and countably paracompact.
- $\omega+1 = \omega_1 \cup \{\omega_1\}$ is compact and zero-dimensional  and $\beta \omega_1 = \omega_1+1$ and so by a standard theorem $\omega_1$ is strongly zero-dimensional.
- There are many clopen subsets that are merely countable and so not homeomorphic to $\omega_1$, e.g. $\omega+1$ and all isolated points (and all the basic sets I discussed).
  I think that $[\omega+1, \rightarrow) = \omega_1\setminus (\omega+1)$ is a clopen subset that is homeomorphic to the whole space.

Comment: I dont understand the practical difference between $\{ \omega_1 \} $ and $\omega_1$. Does the set with one element have different properties than just $\omega_1$ as the first uncountable ordinal?

Comment: @TerezaTizkova of course: one is size 1, the other size \aleph_1$. Ordinals are transitive sets. An element of it is also a subset. Study some set theory?